# Как правильно делать запросы через mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Дело в том, если приходиться делать множество запросов к разным коллекциям, то возникает большая вложенность за счет callback-ов. Может можно еще как-нибудь вынимать результаты по-другому, а то не очень эстетично смотриться код. 
Второй подвопрос. Допустим есть в БД есть коллекция, которая хранит связь - кто на кого подписан:

```
[ { username:"vano", toUsername:"ura"},{ username:"vano",toUsername:"andrey"} ]
```

Вот такой запрос вынимает всех, на кого подписан пользователь:

```
Subscribtions.find({username: user.username},
            'toUsername',
            function (err, subscribtions) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                ...
```

})

Результат получается как массив ОБЪЕКТОВ. Мне дальше необходимо искать информацию о каждом подписчике через `Users.find({username: {$in: usernameSubscrib},...)`, только этого сделать не получается, так как `subscribtions` - не массив СТРОК, а массив ОБЪЕКТОВ. Как тогда производить запрос? 
Спасибо!

Comment: По поводу первого - а) подход Promise б) модуль async, в) разные middleware-обработчики в express.js, каждый из которых по очереди делает свое дело и пишет результат в общий объект (например, `req`). По повод второго - если вам нужен массив строк - попробуйте `.distinct` вместо `.find`, возможно, вы это искали

Comment: @MiKeBu Спасибо, distinct исправил ситуацию, а a) б) и в) - теперь буду знать!

Comment: Поскольку я лишь посоветовал, а вы сами решили, то опубликуйте ваше решение своего же вопроса. И вопрос не будет годами висеть неотвеченным. Рейтинга вам хватит и правила вполне это [позволяют](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

а) подход Promise б) модуль async, в) разные middleware-обработчики в express.js, каждый из которых по очереди делает свое дело и пишет результат в общий объект (например, req). По повод второго - если вам нужен массив строк - попробуйте .distinct вместо .find

Answer (score 0):

Юзай Promise для предотвращения callback hell. 
Почитай про populate в mongoose, это такой себе `inner join` - для объединения коллекций на базе 
ключа. 
Почитай про переменные в express есть глобальные для всего приложения и  локальные для каждой сессии отдельно. 
Это как добавление к пред. ответу.